# Unable to add Timeout expired. Timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2

I have written a stored procedure for saving and updating data (list). The stored procedure updates (any extra data) the duplicate data and any new data is added to the database i.e. the data is checked whether present already in database or not.

The procedure is simple and works well but the problem is I get the above error:

> Unable to add Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to
>   completion of the operation or the server is not responding

I am unable to add the data, but after some time the error resolves and the data gets saved and updated.
What is the exact problem?
Do i need to change the query execution time in sql server management or the query must be optimized?

My procedure is as follows:

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertManuallyUsingXmlExhibitorList] 
    @XML_TRANSACTIONDETAILS nText,
    @exhibitor nvarchar(100)
AS
DECLARE @docHandle int

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @exbitionID nvarchar(100)

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @docHandle OUTPUT, @XML_TRANSACTIONDETAILS


-- CREATE TEMP TABLE

CREATE TABLE #TempTable
(
    maxid nvarchar(200) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  NULL,
    companyname nvarchar(200) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS   NULL,
    email nvarchar(200) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  NULL,
    website nvarchar(200) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    country bigint  NULL,
    contactperson nvarchar(200) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    telphone nvarchar(200) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  NULL,
    mobile nvarchar(200) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    fax nvarchar(200) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    region bigint  NULL,
    status bigint  NULL,
    username bigint  NULL,
    date datetime  NULL,
    category bigint  NULL,
    urlorcatalog nvarchar(200) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    address nvarchar(200) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  NULL,
    lastupdatedby bigint NULL
) 

--  INSERT INTO TEMP TABLE DETAILS OF EMAIL 

INSERT INTO #TempTable
                (
                   maxid,companyname,email,website,country,contactperson,telphone,mobile,fax,region,status,username,date,category,urlorcatalog,address,lastupdatedby
                )

 SELECT
             data.maxid,data.companyname,data.email,data.website,data.country,data.contactperson,data.telphone,data.mobile,data.fax,data.region,data.status,data.username,GETDATE(),data.category,data.urlorcatalog,data.address,data.username

     FROM OPENXML(@docHandle,N'master/TRANSACTION',3)

              WITH
              (
               companyname nvarchar(200),
                website nvarchar(200),
                country bigint ,
                contactperson nvarchar(200),
                telphone nvarchar(200),
                mobile nvarchar(200),
                fax nvarchar(200),
                region bigint,
                status bigint,
                username bigint,                
                category bigint,
                urlorcatalog nvarchar(200),
                email nvarchar(200),                
                maxid nvarchar(200),
                address nvarchar(200)          
              ) as data

--  INSERT INTO TEMP TABLE DETAILS OF EMAIL1 

INSERT INTO #TempTable
                (
                   maxid,companyname,email,website,country,contactperson,telphone,mobile,fax,region,status,username,date,category,urlorcatalog,address,lastupdatedby
                )

 SELECT
             data.maxid,data.companyname,data.email1,data.website,data.country,data.contactperson,data.telphone,data.mobile,data.fax,data.region,data.status,data.username,GETDATE(),data.category,data.urlorcatalog,data.address,data.username

     FROM OPENXML(@docHandle,N'master/TRANSACTION',3)

              WITH
              (
               companyname nvarchar(200),
                website nvarchar(200),
                country bigint ,
                contactperson nvarchar(200),
                telphone nvarchar(200),
                mobile nvarchar(200),
                fax nvarchar(200),
                region bigint,
                status bigint,
                username bigint,                
                category bigint,
                urlorcatalog nvarchar(200),
                email1 nvarchar(200),               
                maxid nvarchar(200),
                dataentrytype nvarchar(200),
                lastupdatedby nvarchar(200),
                address nvarchar(200)           

              ) as data
            WHERE data.email1 !=''


--  INSERT INTO TEMP TABLE DETAILS OF EMAIL2 

INSERT INTO #TempTable
                (
                   maxid,companyname,email,website,country,contactperson,telphone,mobile,fax,region,status,username,date,category,urlorcatalog,address,lastupdatedby
                )

 SELECT
             data.maxid,data.companyname,data.email2,data.website,data.country,data.contactperson,data.telphone,data.mobile,data.fax,data.region,data.status,data.username,GETDATE(),data.category,data.urlorcatalog,data.address,data.username

     FROM OPENXML(@docHandle,N'master/TRANSACTION',3)

              WITH
              (
               companyname nvarchar(200),
                website nvarchar(200),
                country bigint ,
                contactperson nvarchar(200),
                telphone nvarchar(200),
                mobile nvarchar(200),
                fax nvarchar(200),
                region bigint,
                status bigint,
                username bigint,
                category bigint,
                urlorcatalog nvarchar(200),
                email2 nvarchar(200),
                maxid nvarchar(200),                
                address nvarchar(200)

              ) as data

            WHERE data.email2 !=''


--**********************UPDATE TEMP TABLE IF COUNTRY AND REGION IS NULL********************

UPDATE #TempTable 
SET
country=1
WHERE  country=0

UPDATE #TempTable 
SET
region=2
WHERE  region=0

-- CODE TO COUNT  DUPLICATES EMAILS

SELECT
 COUNT
( email)

FROM
    #TempTable T

        WHERE 
              T.email !=''
        AND 
         EXISTS (SELECT  emailinfo.email FROM dbo.emailinfo WHERE email=T.email)



--  TRANSACTION BEGINS HERE


BEGIN TRANSACTION

----------------------  EXHIBITOR LIST   ------------------------------------

    IF  EXISTS ( SELECT  *
                FROM    exibitions
                WHERE   exhibitiorlist=@exhibitor ) 

        BEGIN

        SELECT @exbitionID = EID FROM  exibitions WHERE exhibitiorlist=@exhibitor

        end

    ELSE

        BEGIN

            INSERT INTO exibitions  VALUES (@exhibitor)

            SET @exbitionID = (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY())

        END
-------------  UPADATE EXHIBITOR LIST  -------------------------------------

--DECLARE @RtnStr VARCHAR(MAX)

UPDATE dbo.companyinfo 

SET companyinfo.exblist=RESULT.m2

FROM

(   
select TEMP1.DataID,COALESCE(COMPANY.exblist + ',', '') + @exbitionID as 'm2'
from

        (   
            SELECT Email.DataID,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tmp.email ORDER BY tmp.email ) AS 'RowNumber'
            FROM #TempTable tmp 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN emailinfo Email ON tmp.email =Email.email           

            WHERE 
              tmp.email !=''        
            AND 
            EXISTS (SELECT  emailinfo.email FROM dbo.emailinfo WHERE email=tmp.email)
        )AS TEMP1

    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.companyinfo COMPANY ON TEMP1.DataID =COMPANY.dataId     

    WHERE

    TEMP1.RowNumber =1       


) AS RESULT

WHERE companyinfo.dataId =RESULT.DataID 

IF @@ERROR<>0 BEGIN ROLLBACK TRANSACTION RETURN -101 END


-------------  UPDATE DATE IF EMAIL ALREADY EXISTED  ------------------------

UPDATE dbo.companyinfo 

SET companyinfo.lastupdateddate=RESULT.date

FROM

(   
select TEMP1.date,TEMP1.DataID
from

        (   
            SELECT tmp.date,Email.DataID,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tmp.email ORDER BY tmp.email ) AS 'RowNumber'
            FROM #TempTable tmp 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN emailinfo Email ON tmp.email =Email.email           

            WHERE 
              tmp.email !=''        
            AND 
            EXISTS (SELECT  emailinfo.email FROM dbo.emailinfo WHERE email=tmp.email)
        )AS TEMP1

    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.companyinfo COMPANY ON TEMP1.DataID =COMPANY.dataId     

    WHERE

    TEMP1.RowNumber =1       


) AS RESULT

WHERE companyinfo.dataId =RESULT.DataID 

IF @@ERROR<>0 BEGIN ROLLBACK TRANSACTION RETURN -101 END


-- ******************* UPDATE CATEGORY IF EMAIL ALREADY EXISTED ***********************

UPDATE dbo.companyinfo 

SET companyinfo.category=case when companyinfo.status!=1 and companyinfo.status!=2 and companyinfo.status!=13 and companyinfo.status!=17 then RESULT.category else companyinfo.category end

FROM

(   
select TEMP1.category,TEMP1.status,TEMP1.DataID
from

        (   
            SELECT tmp.category,tmp.status,Email.DataID,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tmp.email ORDER BY tmp.email ) AS 'RowNumber'
            FROM #TempTable tmp 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN emailinfo Email ON tmp.email =Email.email           

            WHERE 
              tmp.email !=''        
            AND 
            EXISTS (SELECT  emailinfo.email FROM dbo.emailinfo WHERE email=tmp.email)
        )AS TEMP1

    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.companyinfo COMPANY ON TEMP1.DataID =COMPANY.dataId     

    WHERE

    TEMP1.RowNumber =1       

) AS RESULT

WHERE companyinfo.dataId =RESULT.DataID  

IF @@ERROR<>0 BEGIN ROLLBACK TRANSACTION RETURN -101 END


-- ******************* UPDATE COMPANY IF EMAIL ALREADY EXISTED ***********************

UPDATE dbo.companyinfo SET companyinfo.companyname=case when companyinfo.companyname='' or companyinfo.companyname=null then RESULT.companyname else companyinfo.companyname end ,
 companyinfo.website= case when companyinfo.website='' OR companyinfo.website IS NULL then RESULT.website else companyinfo.website end ,
 companyinfo.contactperson= case when companyinfo.contactperson='' OR companyinfo.contactperson IS NULL then RESULT.contactperson else companyinfo.contactperson end,companyinfo.country = case when companyinfo.country=1 OR companyinfo.country IS NULL then RESULT.country else companyinfo.country end,
 companyinfo.telphone=case when companyinfo.telphone='' OR companyinfo.telphone IS NULL then RESULT.telphone else companyinfo.telphone end,companyinfo.mobile= case when companyinfo.mobile='' OR companyinfo.mobile IS NULL then RESULT.mobile else companyinfo.mobile end ,
 companyinfo.fax= case when companyinfo.fax='' OR companyinfo.fax IS NULL then RESULT.fax else companyinfo.fax end, companyinfo.region= case when companyinfo.region=2 OR companyinfo.region IS NULL then RESULT.region else companyinfo.region end,companyinfo.address= case when companyinfo.address='' OR companyinfo.address IS NULL then RESULT.address else companyinfo.address end,
 companyinfo.lastupdatedby=RESULT.lastupdatedby
FROM

(   
select TEMP1.companyname,TEMP1.website,TEMP1.contactperson,TEMP1.country, TEMP1.telphone , TEMP1.mobile, TEMP1.fax,TEMP1.region, TEMP1.urlorcatalog,TEMP1.address,TEMP1.lastupdatedby, TEMP1.DataID
from

        (   
            SELECT tmp.companyname,tmp.website,tmp.contactperson,tmp.country,tmp.telphone,tmp.mobile,tmp.fax, tmp.region,tmp.urlorcatalog,tmp.address,tmp.lastupdatedby,Email.DataID,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tmp.email ORDER BY tmp.email ) AS 'RowNumber'
            FROM #TempTable tmp 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN emailinfo Email ON tmp.email =Email.email                                                   
            WHERE 
              tmp.email !=''        
            AND 
            EXISTS (SELECT  emailinfo.email FROM dbo.emailinfo WHERE email=tmp.email)
        )AS TEMP1

    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.companyinfo COMPANY ON TEMP1.DataID =COMPANY.dataId     

    WHERE

    TEMP1.RowNumber =1       

) AS RESULT

WHERE companyinfo.dataId =RESULT.DataID 

IF @@ERROR<>0 BEGIN ROLLBACK TRANSACTION RETURN -101 END



-- ******************** UPDATE STATUS IF EMAIL ALREADY EXISTED ******************


UPDATE dbo.companyinfo 

SET companyinfo.status=RESULT.status

FROM

(   
select TEMP1.status,TEMP1.DataID
from

        (   
            SELECT tmp.email,tmp.status,Email.DataID,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tmp.email ORDER BY tmp.email ) AS 'RowNumber'
            FROM #TempTable tmp 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.emailinfo Email ON tmp.email=Email.email            

            WHERE 
              tmp.email !=''        
            AND 
            EXISTS (SELECT  emailinfo.email FROM dbo.emailinfo WHERE email=tmp.email)
        )AS TEMP1

    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.companyinfo COMPANY ON TEMP1.DataID=COMPANY.dataID  

    where --cmp.status !=8  And
    TEMP1.RowNumber=1       AND
    COMPANY.status !=1          AND 
    COMPANY.status < 6         AND
    TEMP1.status < COMPANY.status

) AS RESULT

WHERE companyinfo.dataID=RESULT.DataID

IF @@ERROR<>0 BEGIN ROLLBACK TRANSACTION RETURN -101 END



--  ************INSERT INTO PRIMARY  TABLE(companyinfo)*************


INSERT INTO dbo.companyinfo
                (
                  dataId,companyname,website,country,contactperson,telphone,mobile,fax,region,status,userid,date,category,urlorcatalog,dataentrytype,address,exblist
              )


SELECT
                          T1.maxid,T1.companyname,T1.website,T1.country,T1.contactperson,T1.telphone,T1.mobile,T1.fax,T1.region,T1.status,T1.username,T1.date,T1.category,T1.urlorcatalog,'MANUAL',T1.address,@exbitionID                   

                        FROM
                        (   
                            SELECT tmpdata.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY maxid ORDER BY maxid ) AS 'RowNumber'
                            FROM 
                            (

                                        SELECT
                                                *

                                        FROM
                                        (
                                                SELECT tmp.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tmp.email ORDER BY tmp.email ) AS 'RowNumber1'
                                                FROM #TempTable tmp 
            --                                      LEFT OUTER JOIN emailinfo Email ON tmp.email=Email.email
                                        )AS T 

                                        WHERE T.RowNumber1=1
                                        AND  T.email !=''
                                        AND 
                                        NOT EXISTS (SELECT  emailinfo.email FROM dbo.emailinfo WHERE email=T.email)


                             )tmpdata


                        )AS T1

                        WHERE 
                    T1.email !=''  AND

                    T1.RowNumber=1

IF @@ERROR<>0 BEGIN ROLLBACK TRANSACTION RETURN -101 END


--  ************INSERT INTO SECONDARY TABLE*************


INSERT INTO emailinfo
        ( 
            DataID,email
            )
SELECT
        T.maxid,T.email

FROM
(
        SELECT tmp.maxid,tmp.email, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tmp.email ORDER BY tmp.email ) AS 'RowNumber'
        FROM #TempTable tmp 
            --LEFT OUTER JOIN emailinfo Email ON tmp.email=Email.email
)AS T 

WHERE T.RowNumber=1
AND  T.email !=''
AND 
NOT EXISTS (SELECT  emailinfo.email FROM dbo.emailinfo WHERE email=T.email)   

 IF @@ERROR<>0 BEGIN ROLLBACK TRANSACTION RETURN -101 END



COMMIT TRANSACTION

DROP TABLE #TempTable

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @docHandle
```

The error persist even for very few entries around 4-5 updates/insert.

Comment: Could you include the code for the stored procedure?

Answer (score 2):

When you try to modify a large table by using the table designer in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, you may receive an error message that is similar to the following:

> Unable to modify table. Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed
>   prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

**[RESOLUTION](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/915849)**:

To resolve this behavior, use one of the following methods:

- Click to clear the Override connection string time-out value for
  table designer updates check box for the table designer and for the
  database designer in SQL Server Management Studio.
- Specify a high setting in the Transaction time-out after box for the
  table designer and for the database designer in SQL Server Management
  Studio.
- Modify the large table by using Transact-SQL statements in Query
  Editor in SQL Server Management Studio.

References :

[Time out](https://serverfault.com/questions/96815/timeout-saving-table-in-sql-server)

Comment: I tried changing the Transaction time-out after from 30 secs to 60 secs still the problem is not solved.

Answer (score 1):

Solution.

Let’s increased the time out value to 65,535, the maximum value.

We clicked on the Tools menu, then clicked on “Options”, and clicked on “Designers” on the left panel. After that, we changed the value in the “Transaction time-out after:” textbox.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**To resolve this behavior, use one of the following methods:**

Click to clear the **Override connection string time-out value for table designer** updates check box for the table designer and for the database designer in SQL Server Management Studio.

Specify a high setting in the **Transaction time-out after** box for the table designer and for the database designer in SQL Server Management Studio.

Modify the large table by using Transact-SQL statements in Query Editor in SQL Server Management Studio.